# HTML 5 Geo Location not working on Live Site

Tags: html, geolocation, gps

I tried to use the HTML 5 Geo Location example from w3schools.com. It worked in their "Try it Yourself" and on my localhost but the lat and lon values were not accurate enough though. Therefore, I decided to test it on my smartphone as in the site they mentioned that "Note: Geolocation is most accurate for devices with GPS, like smartphone". Therefore, I hosted the page on my domain stardatings.in and to my surprise it didn't work when I clicked the button. You can check. Its neither working from my laptop and nor from my smartphone browser. But when I tried to access the w3schools Geo Location Try it Editor page from my mobile it worked there with accurate location. But it didn't work when I used it on the php page and uploaded on my live website. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got the solution. It only works on site enabled with HTTPS.